# How to develop a chat bot with Microsoft Bot Sdk and LUIS conected

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I started to learn how to develop bots with the Microsoft Bot SDK and Language Understanding Intelligent Service (LUIS)

I've seen a lot of guides and samples but I see two different ways, and I don't know how to mix them.

I find a lot of samples like this https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/PizzaBot where you can get advanced used of the chat bot features, but the data from LUIS comes froma json you need to download and add to your project each time it changes.

I find another sample https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Chat-Bot-using-Bot-1211d6ce where the project gets direct conection to LUIS and deserialices the data, but in that I cannot find how to do chain dialogs.

What I want is to use IDialogs but without need to download the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you never need to download the json. The [json](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/PizzaBot/Model/PizzaBot.json) the PizzaBot is providing is the LUIS model, for you to **import** to LUIS as an existing application. You might want to read the [Importing and Exporting Applications](https://www.luis.ai/Help#ImportingApps) section from the docs.

That being clarified, if you want to get started on LUIS (and many other features of the BotFramework) you can check the [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/) repository where you will find task focused samples and demo samples both in C# and Node.js.

In particular, I think you will find useful the [LUIS sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-LUIS) and the [MultiDialogs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs) one

Comment: But in the second sampled I posted they use LUIS without download the json.

Comment: In the first sample the are not downloading the json either. The code is not downloading the json. They just downloaded manually the json and added to repo, so if someone wants to run the sample they have an existing model to import.

Comment: Also, the second sample is not using the LuisDialog and it's using Luis "manually" calling the API, etc..I recommend looking into the sample I provided.

Comment: I finally managed to make it work, and with form flows, unfortunatelly my boss did not seem very impressed, so I will stop the project for the moment. Thanks